# Type of Assimilation

Tags: phonology, phonetics

So, assimilation may be of three degrees: complete, partial and intermediate.
But I don't understand the difference between intermediate and complete assimilation.

For example wha**t’s** [wɒt**s**] is a short form of what is [wɒt i**z**].What degree of assimilation is it?

And one more question...
Why there is an optional **"h"** in transcription of words "when" [wen – **h**wen] and "what" [**(h)** wɒt]. Why is it even here?

Comment: The optional H is because that's the formal (you might say unassimilated) pronunciation of when —just as if the W and the H were swapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Complete assimilation" usually means that the assimilated sound becomes exactly the same as the sound that it assimilates to. In English, this kind of assimilation is generally optional and occurs more often in fast speech, usually between different words or different parts of compound words. For example, in the word "horse-shoe", the s sound of "horse" might be completely assimilated to the following sh sound of "shoe".

"Partial assimilation" is very common in English, but it can be difficult to notice. When it occurs, the assimilated sound is basically the same sound, but adjusted to be a bit more similar to another sound. For example, in the word "click", the /l/ is slightly devoiced due to partial assimilation to the voiceless consonant /k/. A devoiced /l/ is not considered to be a distinct sound from a voiced /l/ in English.

"Intermediate assimilation" is also very common in English. It just means that the assimilated sound changes in some features to become a different sound, but it doesn't become completely the same as the sound it assimilates to. In what’s [wɒts], the /z/ is assimilated and becomes the different sound [s] due to the preceding /t/; it assimilates in the feature of "voicing" to become a voiceless consonant, but it is not completely assimilated: complete assimilation would be if it were turned into another [t]. This kind of assimilation occurs in contractions and with the common word suffixes -s and -ed, and it is mandatory.

(Source: see post #14 on [this site](http://www.efl.ru/forum/threads/29686/). Note: this post has some errors, especially in the phonetic transcriptions, so don't rely on it! I'm just posting it to acknowledge that I used it to help write this answer.)